# Leafet setLatLng unmounts and mounts markers continuously, preventing events from firing

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to visualise 500+ vehicles using leaflet. When the position of a marker (vehicle) changes, it will move slowly to reach the destination (using `requestAnimationFrame` and leaflet's 'native' `setLatLng` since I don't want to update the state directly). It works well, but I also have a click listener on each marker and notice that it never fires. I soon realised that leaflet has been updating the marker continuously (the DOM element keeps blinking in the inspector). I attempted to log something to see if the component actually re-renders, but it doesn't. Seems like leaflet is messing with the DOM element under the hood.

[image]

```
const Marker = React.memo(function Marker({ plate, coors, prevCoors }) {
  const markerRef = React.useRef();
  const [activeVehicle, handleActiveVehicleUpdate] = useActiveVehicle();
  const heading = prevCoors != null ? GeoHelpers.computeHeading(prevCoors, coors) : 0;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (prevCoors == null) return;

    const [prevLat, prevLong] = prevCoors;
    const [lat, long] = coors;
    let animationStartTime;

    const animateMarker = timestamp => {
      if (animationStartTime == null) animationStartTime = timestamp;

      const progress = (timestamp - animationStartTime) / 5000;

      if (progress > 1) return;

      const currLat = prevLat + (lat - prevLat) * progress;
      const currLong = prevLong + (long - prevLong) * progress;

      const position = new LatLng(currLat, currLong);

      markerRef.current.leafletElement.setLatLng(position);

      requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
    };

    const animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);

    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
  }, [coors, prevCoors]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (plate === '60C23403') console.log('re-render!');
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  });

  return (
    <LeafletMarker
      icon={createIcon(plate === activeVehicle, heading)}
      position={prevCoors != null ? prevCoors : coors}
      onClick={handleActiveVehicleUpdate(plate, coors)}
      ref={markerRef}
    >
      <Tooltip>{plate}</Tooltip>
    </LeafletMarker>
  );
});
```

How do I prevent this behaviour from leaflet? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `React.useEffect(() => {
    if (plate === '60C23403') console.log('re-render!');
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);` this doesn't work on re render since you passed a list of dependency that is empty. The effect will be triggered only one time, on first render. Avoid second parameter if you want to see the rerenders.

Comment: @nubinub Oh sorry my bad. I will check again and keep you updated

Comment: @nubinub I checked and the component still re-renders. I'm now pretty sure that the DOM manipulation is made by leaflet